# How to prepare invoice and release invoice by code

Tags: cloud, erp, acumatica

I am trying to create an process page to import SO and I need to complete SO automatically. Here's my code

```
 using (var scope = new PXTransactionScope())
        {
            SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
            ImportSFA importGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ImportSFA>();
            order.IsConvert = true;
            importGraph.ImportProcessing.Update(order);
            SOOrder newOrder = new SOOrder();
            graph.Document.Current = newOrder;
            newOrder.Status = "N";
            //newOrder.OrderNbr = order.OrderNbr;
            newOrder.OrderDate = order.OrderDate;
            newOrder.RequestDate = order.OrderDate;
            newOrder.OrderDesc = order.Note;
            SOOrderExt a = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(newOrder);
            a.UsrRouteID = order.Route;
            a.UsrTrueRoute = true;
            var graphExt = graph.GetExtension<SOOrderEntryExt1>();


            // cap nhat order type theo don tu PDA gui ve
            if (order.OrderType == "PA")
            {
                newOrder.OrderType = "SO";
            }

            else if (order.OrderType == "IV")
            {
                newOrder.OrderType = "IN";
            }
            else
            {
                newOrder.OrderType = "CS";
            }
            if (newOrder.OrderType == "CS")
            {
                newOrder.ExtRefNbr = "123";
                Branch branch = PXSelect<Branch>.Select(graph);
                CashAccount ca =
                    PXSelect<CashAccount, Where<CashAccount.branchID, Equal<Required<CashAccount.branchID>>>>.Select
                        (graph,
                            branch.BranchID).FirstTableItems.FirstOrDefault();
                if (ca != null)
                {
                    newOrder.CashAccountID = ca.CashAccountID;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new PXException("Cannot find the Cash Account.");
                }

            }

            newOrder.CustomerOrderNbr = order.OrderNbr;
            PXSelectBase<BAccount> cmdBaccount = new PXSelect<BAccount,
                Where<BAccount.acctCD, Equal<Required<BAccount.acctCD>>>>(graph);
            PXSelectBase<SalesPerson> cmdSalesman = new PXSelect<SalesPerson,
                Where<SalesPerson.salesPersonCD, Equal<Required<SalesPerson.salesPersonCD>>>>(graph);
            BAccount bacc = cmdBaccount.Select(order.CustomerID);
            SalesPerson salesman = cmdSalesman.Select(order.SalesmanID);
            if (bacc != null)
            {
                newOrder.CustomerID = bacc.BAccountID;
            }
            if (salesman != null)
            {
                newOrder.SalesPersonID = salesman.SalesPersonID;
            }

            graph.Document.Cache.Update(graph.Document.Current);
            graph.Persist();

            //Insert line
            PXSelectBase<DMSSODetail> lines = new PXSelect<DMSSODetail,
                Where<DMSSODetail.orderNbr, Equal<Required<DMSSODetail.orderNbr>>>>(graph);
            INLocation location = null;
            if (newOrder.OrderType == "SO")
            {
                foreach (DMSSODetail item in lines.Select(order.OrderNbr))
                {
                    if (item.IsFree != true)
                    {
                        INSite site = PXSelect<INSite,
                            Where<INSite.siteCD, Equal<Required<INSite.siteCD>>>>.Select(graph, item.Warehouse);

                        SOLine line = graph.Transactions.Insert();
                        line.InventoryID = item.InventoryID;

                        if (site != null)
                        {
                            line.SiteID = site.SiteID;
                        }
                        line.Qty = item.ConfirmQty;
                        SOLine updated = (SOLine) graph.Transactions.Cache.Update(line);
                    }
                    else if (item.IsFree == true && item.ManualDiscount == true)
                    {
                        INSite site = PXSelect<INSite,
                            Where<INSite.siteCD, Equal<Required<INSite.siteCD>>>>.Select(graph, item.Warehouse);

                        SOLine line = graph.Transactions.Insert();
                        line.InventoryID = item.InventoryID;
                        line.ManualDisc = true;
                        line.IsFree = true;
                        SOLineExt extLine = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(line);
                        extLine.UsrManualPromoID = item.PromoDiscID;
                        if (site != null)
                        {
                            line.SiteID = site.SiteID;
                        }
                        line.Qty = item.ConfirmQty;

                        SOLine updated = (SOLine) graph.Transactions.Cache.Update(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (newOrder.OrderType == "IN" || newOrder.OrderType == "CS")
            {
                foreach (DMSSODetail item in lines.Select(order.OrderNbr))
                {
                    INSite site = PXSelect<INSite,
                        Where<INSite.siteCD, Equal<Required<INSite.siteCD>>>>.Select(graph, item.Warehouse);

                    SOLine line = graph.Transactions.Insert();
                    line.InventoryID = item.InventoryID;

                    if (site != null)
                    {
                        line.SiteID = site.SiteID;
                    }

                    //Search Location
                    INLocation loc = PXSelect<INLocation, Where<INLocation.locationCD,
                        Equal<Required<INLocation.locationCD>>>>.Select(graph, item.WHLocation);
                    if (loc != null)
                    {
                        line.LocationID = loc.LocationID;
                        location = loc;
                    }

                    line.ManualDisc = true; //Prevent Acu auto discount.
                    line.IsFree = item.IsFree;
                    SOLineExt extLine = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(line);
                    extLine.UsrManualPromoID = item.PromoDiscID;
                    line.Qty = item.ConfirmQty;
                    SOLine updated = (SOLine) graph.Transactions.Cache.Update(line);
                    graph.Transactions.Current = updated;

                    //Search DMSSODetailSplit
                    PXSelectBase<DMSSODetailSplit> splits = new PXSelect<DMSSODetailSplit,
                        Where<DMSSODetailSplit.orderNbr, Equal<Required<DMSSODetailSplit.orderNbr>>,
                            And<DMSSODetailSplit.inventoryID, Equal<Required<DMSSODetailSplit.inventoryID>>,
                                And<DMSSODetailSplit.isFree, Equal<Required<DMSSODetailSplit.isFree>>,
                                    And<DMSSODetailSplit.promoDiscID, Equal<Required<DMSSODetailSplit.promoDiscID>>>
                                    >>>>
                        (graph);

                    foreach (DMSSODetailSplit split in
                        splits.Select(item.OrderNbr, item.InventoryID, item.IsFree, item.PromoDiscID))
                    {
                        // goi ham insert bar code
                        graphExt.InsertScannedBarcode(split.InventoryID, split.LotSerialNbr, newOrder);

                    }
                }
            }

            int index = 0;
            foreach (SOLine item in graph.Transactions.Select())
            {
                if (item.IsFree == true)
                {
                    SOLine oldRow = item;
                    item.LocationID =
                        ((SOLine) graph.Transactions.Select()[(index - 1) < 0 ? 0 : (index - 1)]).LocationID;
                    graph.Transactions.Cache.RaiseFieldUpdated<SOLine.locationID>(item, oldRow.LocationID);
                }
                index++;
            }

            graph.Persist();

            importGraph.Actions.PressSave();
            //graph.prepareInvoice.Press();

            //kiem tra neu la don hang CS thi tu dong tao va release invoice
            if (newOrder.OrderType == "CS")
            {
                graphExt.prepareInvoice.Press();
                SOInvoiceEntry invoiceGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOInvoiceEntry>();
                PXResultset<ARInvoice> arInv = PXSelectJoin<ARInvoice,
                    InnerJoin<SOOrderShipment, On<ARInvoice.docType,
                        Equal<SOOrderShipment.invoiceType>,
                        And<ARInvoice.refNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.invoiceNbr>>>>
                    , Where<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr>>
                        , And<SOOrderShipment.invtDocType, Equal<Required<SOOrderShipment.invtDocType>>>>>
                    .Select(invoiceGraph, newOrder.OrderNbr, "CSL");
                invoiceGraph.Document.Current = arInv;
                invoiceGraph.Save.Press();
                //release invoice
                invoiceGraph.release.Press();
            }
            scope.Complete();
        }
```

When I process I get this error

24/01/2015 5:48:23 CH Error:
Error #140: One or more items have not been processed.

Invoice

at PX.Data.PXProcessing`1.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__11(List`1 list)
   at PX.Data.PXLongOperation.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__4()

I do not know how to fix. Please help me. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Your sample is too complex to troubleshoot, and it uses extensions and customizations specific to your organization. I would recommend to cut it down to a sample that shows the problem happening on the demo company, without any customizations involved.

Comment: How do you imagine posibilities of others with helping you? You didn't provide SOOrderEntryExt1, SOLineExt. The only thing, that I can tell you is that maybe there is something wrong in your data because error message says "One or more items have not been processed". So maybe some items where processed. Please provide mentioned classes, provide sql, which will give troubled data, mention please page (ar301000 for example) and then maybe it can be easier to help you